# Definition of $Λ^*: End(Ω(J))→End(Ω(C))$ from Abel Jacobi map $Λ$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $C$ be a hyper elliptic curve of genus $2$. Let $J(C)$ be its Jacobean.
There is Abel Jacobi map $Λ:C→J(C)$.

Let $Ω(J)$ and $Ω(C)$ be space of holomorphic differential form on $J$ and $C$ respectively.

Then, how can we define $Λ^*: End(Ω(J))→End(Ω(C))$ naturally from $Λ$ ?
Thank you for your help.

P.S : $Λ^*$ appears in $368p$ of https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/journal/pdf/jms210205.pdf without no explanation.

Comment: Please stop making trivial edits to bump your question. This map is just pullback: the map $\Lambda$ gives a map on differentials and then you go from there.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be careful from now on. Could you tell me what exactly $Λ^*( \phi)=$ ?  $\in End(Ω(C))$( $\phi \in End(Ω(J))$)